# MySQL stored procedures Can't create

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to create stored procedure I create it via Sequel Pro editor.
Here is my query:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE 'selectValue' (IN surnamePart INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
SELECT id FROM mbus_clients WHERE second_name like surnamePart
END;;
```

It says what mistake is near ''selectValue' (IN surnamePart INT)
LANGUAGE SQL'. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use backticks to escape names, not quotes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `selectValue` (IN surnamePart INT)
```